# VB.NET: Draw pen inside, not outside

Tags: vb.net, path, drawing

I think I once read that a pen can be set up in such a way that it draws "inside" a path, and not outside.
I don't want my path to be enlarged. 
To be specific, I would like to paint a border around my path, and the border should not go outside the path.

This unfortunately enlarges my path:

```
    Dim nPen As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 15)
    g.DrawPath(nPen, nPath)
```

If anybody understands what I want to do, I would be glad to get a reply!
Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [**Pen.Alignment property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.alignment.aspx).

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Can you please set your comment as a answer instead?

Comment: Be sure to dispose of your pen after you are done using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Pen.Alignment property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.alignment.aspx). It can have following values ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z62ath7a.aspx)):

- Center: Specifies that the Pen object is centered over the theoretical line.
- Inset: Specifies that the Pen is positioned on the inside of the theoretical line.
- Outset: Specifies the Pen is positioned on the outside of the theoretical line.
- Left: Specifies the Pen is positioned to the left of the theoretical line.
- Right: Specifies the Pen is positioned to the right of the theoretical line.

You'll need the `Inset` value.

*Code example.* You could use it like this:

```
Using nPen As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 15) With {.Alignment = Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset}
    g.DrawPath(nPen, nPath)
End Using
```

(Note that I am using [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to ensure the object is being disposed.)